# Trying to create an algo that creates a spanning tree with least number of edges removed from a unweighed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to create an algo that will get a spanning tree with root node such that, the spanning tree will have least number of edges removed from Original Graph G.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Corrected. least number of edges removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any connected graph, the spanning tree always contains n-1 edges where n is the number of nodes in the graph. So you will have to remove all the remaining edges. (If I have understood your question correctly)

Even for disconnected graphs, the number of edges in a spanning tree is defined by the number of components and number of nodes in each component.

Comment: how does that affect selection of root node among the Spanning tree? are you saying, irrespective of root node selection, the number of edges removed will remain same?

Comment: How do u define the root node? AFAIR the root node can be selected in arbitrary manner. And yes for any 'tree' rooted or unrooted the number of edges is one less than the number of nodes.

Comment: Okay, is there a chance that the a edge will be removed from spanning tree, which does not form  a  cycle? Also, this is same as spanned edge, right?Like, if the edge is present in a graph and not present in Spanning tree, its a spanned edge of the Tree.